# What makes a heap allocated object "referenced" in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, allocation

What, in C++, determines that a heap allocated object to be referenced? In his book, Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++, Mark Allen Weiss writes "When an object is allocated by new is no longer referenced, the delete operation must be applied to the object (through a pointer)" I find this sentence a bit confusing, all I understand is that a pointer holds a reference to a memory address, but how is the object that represents this address referenced by something else? And when that something else is no longer referencing it, I have to call delete?

Comment: `int *a = new int{1}; int *b = a;` Both `a` and `b` reference the memory allocated by `new int{1}`

Comment: Ok, so if this memory address is referenced by a and then b references a, is the proper order of deletetion reversed? As in I delete b then delete a? This seems problematic

Comment: @AbdelRahmanMahmoud In that example, there's only one heap allocated object, so only one object to delete.

Comment: @Schwartz so I only delete a, then b's reference to a is automatically undone?

Comment: No it is not. Both `a` and `b` still will point to the same location after the delete.  However you are not permitted to use `b` after you delete `a`

Comment: @dresherhm So it's better, to say b = nullptr; first then delete a, correct?

Comment: That would be okay but unnecessary in many cases. Also after the delete `a` will still point to the memory that you deleted however again you are not permitted to dereference the pointer after you freed the memory.

Comment: @drescherjm Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: *The book is incorrect*.

Comment: @user253751 Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: @AbdelRahmanMahmoud It's simply incorrect. There is no rule about "referencing" and `delete`. The rule is that you should `delete` objects allocated by `new` *when you don't need them any more*.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, I understand what you mean. I did feel like the wording was just off, which could create big problems for beginners and would've been a bigger problem if the book was about C++ itself, not data structures and algorithms in general.

Comment: @AbdelRahmanMahmoud Don't set pointers to nullptr unless you have some specific reason to. Some people get into the habit of setting pointers to nullptr without really thinking about why they're doing it and it causes pain and suffering.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that does make sense since just de-allocating the memory is enough, I guess this could become a bad habit where a pointer can be set to null too soon.

Comment: @AbdelRahmanMahmoud There are a lot of reasons it becomes a bad habit. One is that if you have two pointers to the same object, you can't always set both to `nullptr`, so you can't ensure that pointers are valid or `nullptr` anyway, so there's no benefit. The other is that it can hide information that code relies on, such as the fact that a pointer previously pointed to a valid object. You can't just assume it's safe to insert a `b = nullptr`; after a `free (b);` in some code.

Comment: "Moreover, could you please tell me about sources I can read that would clarify the usage of memory in C++?" <- this is off-topic

Comment: @user253751 Agreed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't get too obsessed with the precise choice of language there. What he's trying to say is that if you allocate an object on the heap, it's your responsibility to de-allocate it when you're done with it. Otherwise, it will remain valid and waste memory.

You can be completely done with an object even though it's still referenced. And precisely when you remove all references to the object and when you de-allocate it is up to you. The point is simply that you definitely don't want to try to use it after you de-allocate and and you also don't want to fail to de-allocate a large number of objects over a long period of time and waste memory.

Fortunately, in modern C++, you have a number of tools to make this much easier including move semantics, `unique_ptr`, and many more.

Answer (score 4):

The book is incorrect. There is no rule about "referencing" and `delete`. The rule is that you should `delete` objects allocated by `new` *when you don't need them any more*.

When the book says the object is "no longer referenced", it *actually means* the object is no longer needed. You must have at least one reference to the object, otherwise you can't even `delete` it!

"Referenced" means that your program knows the address of the object, because it's stored in a variable.

Answer (score 3):

Just to illustrate something like

```
int* a = new int;
int* b = a;
```

It would look like this:

```
+---
| a | --\
+---+    \     +-----------------------+
          >--> | heap allocated memory |
+---+    /     +-----------------------+
| b | --/
+---+
```

Both of the pointers `a` and `b` are pointing to the exact same memory.

If you `delete a` after this then both `a` and `b` are invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

> how is the object that represents this address referenced by something
> else?

That means that something else in your program is holding a pointer (or a reference, which for our purposes amounts to the same thing) to the heap-allocated-object's memory location.

> And when that something else is no longer referencing it, I have to
> call delete?

Well, you don't *have* to -- the alternative is to just forget about the object and never delete it at all, which is known as a memory leak.  The only problem with that is that if you don't delete the object, the RAM (and any other resources) taken up by that object will never be released (at least not until your program exits), and if you keep leaking objects, eventually your computer will run out of RAM and grind to a halt.  So for very short-lived programs it might be okay to be sloppy and not delete objects that are no longer referenced, but in general it's better to clean up after yourself.

> Moreover, could you please tell me about sources I can read that would
> clarify the usage of memory in C++?

Any decent C++ book should have a section on it; in general the best practice is to use smart-pointers (like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`) rather than plain old C-style pointers whenever you are working with heap-allocated objects.  That way is much less error-prone, since you never have to figure out when is the correct time to call `delete`, since the pointer-class will automatically call delete for you at the correct time.